# Unterschiedliche Aussprache des ST

Tags: german-to-english, pronunciation

Wenn ich ein Wort wie

- einst
- einstig
- einstweilig

sage, spreche ich das *s* in *st* wie *s* in Englisch.

Aber habe ich ein *st* wie in diesen Wörtern:

- Einsturz
- Einstieg
- Einstimmung

dann spreche ich es wie *sh* in Englisch. Wieso? Was ist die Regel?

Comment: I've no idea what you're asking. You can ask in English, if that's easier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You fell over one of the few cases where German pronounciation isn't stable in regard to spelling. Fortunately, there's an easy rule:

**Einst-weilig** has the *st* at the end of the syllable. In these cases the *t* is just appended to the *s* and it sounds as English *st*.

**Ein-sturz** has the *st* at the beginning of the syllable. In these cases, it sounds as English *sh* plus a *t*.

Now try **feststellen**.

Comment: how to know the beginning and the end of the syllable of german words

Comment: @user26646 Please ask a new question, do not use comments for discussion. That's not how stackexchange works. Please take the tour.

Comment: One more aspect: The pronounciation of the ST is different in different parts of Germany! In Baden (in the south) any ST is pronounced like "scht" (the SH in English) while near the coast in the north all STs always seem (not 100% sure) to be pronounced like in "einst" in Hochdeutsch. In both cases the two STs in "fe**stst**ellen" are pronounced the same way...