# Schtein vs. Stein

Tags: spelling

Weshalb wird Stein nicht mit **"sch"** am Anfang geschrieben, obwohl (jedenfalls würde ich das behaupten) die korrekte bzw. verbreiteste Art der Aussprache **"Schtein"** ist?

(ebenso: **"Straße"** und **"Schtraße"**)

---

Meine Vermutung ist, dass es etwas mit dem Laut danach zu tun hat und "p", "t", etc. das Auftauchen von "sch" verhindern.

> Schwein 
> Schreien 
> Schpaß 
> Schtraße 
> schlank

Oder schpreche ich Schtein einfach nur falsch aus? ;)

**Edit:**

Ich habe in den amtlichen Regeln Folgendes gefunden:

> §27 Für den Laut [sch] am Anfang des Wortstammes vor folgendem [p] oder [t] schreibt man s statt sch.

Daher nehme ich an, dass meine Vermutung korrekt ist. Trotzdem bleibt mir die Frage weshalb das so ist.

Weiterer Gedanke:

Das aus dem Englischen stammende Wort Streik wird mit [sch] am Anfang gesprochen, obwohl das im Englischen ja nicht so ist. **Gibt es dafür eine Erklärung?**

Comment: Ähnliche [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/39568/1696).

Comment: @guidot Danke, hatte ich bei meiner Suche nicht gefunden. Beantwortet aber leider meine Frage nicht, daher würde ich diese Frage hier offen lassen. Mich interessieren auch mögliche Erklärungsansätze weshlab das so ist.

Comment: Im Hamburger Dialekt z.B. eines Helmut Schmidt werden st und sp ohne sch-Laut tatsächlich as s-t oder s-p ausgesprochen, was ein wenig dafür spricht, dass sie sprachhistorisch etwas anderes sind als andere Kombinationen mit sch, und dass es nicht nur eine Festlegung aus der Rechtschreibung ist.

Comment: Ist historisch gewachsen. Wurde früher auch mit ST gesprochen. Siehe auch "stone" im Englischen.

Comment: Weshalb wird die Frage negativ bewertet? Habe hier noch keinen Kommentar gefunden, der mich auf Fehler hinweist.

Answer (score 4):

Zwischen den Kombinationen ST, SP einerseits und SCHL, SCHM, SCHN, SCHR, SCHW gibt es mehrere Unterschiede:

1. Zumindest einige der Wörter mit SCHR und SCHL gehen etymologisch auf SKR, SKL zurück (z.B. das Wort *schreiben),* so dass eine Schreibung mit dem auf SK zurückgehenden SCH gerechtfertigt ist. Die Wörter mit ST, SP gehen hingegen nie auf *SKT, *SKP zurück.
2. ST und SP können mit weiteren Konsonanten kombiniert sein, nämlich STR, SPL, SPR. Eine Schreibung mit SCH würde also zu fünf aufeinanderfolgenden Konsonantenbuchstaben führen (*SCHTR usw.).
3. ST und – in geringerem Mass – SP kommen nicht nur im Anlaut vor, sondern auch im Inlaut, vgl. Wörter wie *Ast, Knospe, machst, höchst* (wenn sie auch in der heute verbreiteten Standardaussprache anders ausgesprochen werden)
4. ST und SP sind Kombinationen mit Plosiven, die anderen hingegen Kombinationen mit Sonoranten.

Ich kenne allerdings keine Untersuchungen darüber, welche Gründe entscheidend gewesen sind. Zumindest im normalisierten Mittelhochdeutschen werden eher SW, SM usw. verwendet.

Comment: Was wäre das Problem von 5 aufeinanderfolgenden Konsonanten?

Comment: In Wiktionary ist genau 1 deutsches Wort eingetragen, das mit mehr als 4 unmittelbar aufeinanderfolgenden Konsonanten beginnt, nämlich [Schtschi](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schtschi). Dabei handelt es sich allerdings um ein russisches Lehnwort.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Und das wird im Russischen laut wiktionary auch bloß щи geschrieben, schtsch ist also nur ein einzelner Buchstabe (щ).

Comment: Punkt 2 ist wichtiger als man denken mag und Punkt 4 lässt sich auch rein graphemisch formulieren (vgl. Längenhierarchie nach Beatrice Primus): _ſt(r)_ und _ſp(r)_ vs. _ſchm_, _ſchn_, _ſchr_, _ſchw_  mit je zwei Ober-/Unterlängen – _ſchl_ sowie _ſpl_ sind wegen der geringen Breite akzeptabel.

Answer (score 2):

Was ich bei meiner "Recherche" erfahren habe, ist, dass es bei der Rechtschreibung bestimmte Prinzipien zu beachten gibt.
Bei der Schreibung von *scht* als *st* und *schp* als *sp* stehen sich wohl besonders das **phonetische Prinzip** (*Wir schreiben die Laute, die wir hören, und wir können das verlauten, was wir sehen.*) und das **ästhetische Prinzip** (*Regelmäßige Schreibungen, die aber nur in bestimmten Kontexten gelten bzw. in bestimmten Fällen regelmäßig allgemeingültige Regeln außer Kraft setzen*) gegenüber.

In diesem Fall scheint wohl einfach das ästhetische Prinzip in den Rechtschreibreformen als gewichtiger bewertet worden zu sein.

Comment: Die Schreibung "st" bzw. "sp" für /ʃt/ bzw. /ʃp/ ist älter als sämtliche Rechtschreibreformen.

Comment: @Uwe Ja, aber das bedeutet ja nicht, dass die Schreibuneng nicht in einer der vergangenen Reformen geändert hätte werden können. Stattdessen wurden "st" und "sp" wohl als ästhetisch schöner bewertet als "scht" und "schp".